# Stage3DProxy in a Worker

Tags: actionscript-3, stage3d, away3d

I'm attempting to put an Away3d in a worker to separate the 3D and the UI and reduce performance lag on mobile.

As soon as the Away3D attempts to get a free proxy

```
stage3DProxy = stage3DManager.getFreeStage3DProxy();
```

I get the error

```
Too many Stage3D instances used!
    at away3d.core.managers::Stage3DManager/getFreeStage3DProxy()[C:\workspace\flash\libs\lib_pano_away3d\src\away3d\core\managers\Stage3DManager.as:98]
    at away3d.containers::View3D/onAddedToStage()[C:\workspace\flash\libs\lib_pano_away3d\src\away3d\containers\View3D.as:931]
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
```

Does anyone know if there are issues with loading Stage3D in a Worker?

Comment: I would 'assume' that the `stage.stage3Ds` vector is zero within a Worker context. You could write a quick test for this of course as Away3d does not test for zero before requesting a proxy. Even if you could get a stage3D within a worker, the rendering context would not work correctly. You *might* be able to use it with PixelBender to do some CUDA-style GPU processing (but that is a BIG assumption and I would say that would not work either), workers have no graphics context and do not have access any stage display list and this is like any other UI framework as most are not thread safe

Comment: Right thanks. So would you suggest that instead of running Away3d In a separate thread, it may be more prudent to run the other UI in another thread... or as I've just read - workers can't access the stage, so they wouldn't do anything anyway..

Comment: A starting point (as always) is to do a search on the error msg.... https://www.google.com/search?q=Too+many+Stage3D+instances+used&gbv=1&sei=rsStVsvAPIHv-AHG36ygCg

Comment: Thanks @1202 Program Alarm, obviously I've done a lot of that and got nowhere, hence asking here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't run stage3D in a worker because the worker can't access the stage or any display lists.